# Joining 3 tables on sql and checking conditions

Tags: mysql

```
SelectClassicModels.Orders.CustomerNumber,
ClassicModels.CUSTOMERS.CUSTOMERNAME,     
ClassicModels.Employees.LASTNAME,
ClassicModels.Employees.firstNAME,
ClassicModels.employees.EmployeeNumber 
from ClassicModels.Orders

join 
ClassicModels.Customers
on ClassicModels.Orders.CustomerNumber = ClassicModels.Customers.CUSTOMERNUMBER

join

ClassicModels.EMPLOYEES
on ClassicModels.Employees.EMPLOYEENUMBER = ClassicModels.CUSTOMERS.SalesRepEmployeeNumber
```

Those three tables when joined work just fine, but when I try and add these modifiers, they don't work

```
group by ClassicModels.Orders.CustomerNumber
having count(ClassicModels.Orders.CustomerNumber) < 4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, welcome to StackOverflow!

I've re-formatted your SQL using my favorite tool, which I can provide a link to if you're interested. I've also added aliases to help make it more "readable". (The aliases are the lowercase bits after the table name in the `FROM` and `JOIN` clauses.)

```
SELECT orders.CustomerNumber,
       customers.CustomerName,
       employees.LastName,
       employees.FirstName,
       employees.EmployeeNumber

FROM CLASSICMODELS.ORDERS orders

JOIN CLASSICMODELS.CUSTOMERS customers
  ON orders.CustomerNumber = customers.CustomerNumber

JOIN CLASSICMODELS.EMPLOYEES employees
  ON employees.EmployeeNumber = customers.SalesRepEmployeeNumber
```

Now that we've got that done. Let's add your `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` clauses.

`GROUP BY` clauses have to have **ALL** of the columns used in the `SELECT` clause in them. (I'm not sure why. I haven't looked it up, but I just know that's how it works. :) )

```
SELECT orders.CustomerNumber,
       customers.CustomerName,
       employees.LastName,
       employees.FirstName,
       employees.EmployeeNumber

FROM CLASSICMODELS.ORDERS orders

JOIN CLASSICMODELS.CUSTOMERS customers
  ON orders.CustomerNumber = customers.CustomerNumber

JOIN CLASSICMODELS.EMPLOYEES employees
  ON employees.EmployeeNumber = customers.SalesRepEmployeeNumber

GROUP BY orders.CustomerNumber,
         customers.CustomerName,
         employees.LastName,
         employees.FirstName,
         employees.EmployeeNumber
```

Now that should work. Then you just have to add your `HAVING` clause in there.

```
SELECT orders.CustomerNumber,
       customers.CustomerName,
       employees.LastName,
       employees.FirstName,
       employees.EmployeeNumber

FROM CLASSICMODELS.ORDERS orders

JOIN CLASSICMODELS.CUSTOMERS customers
  ON orders.CustomerNumber = customers.CustomerNumber

JOIN CLASSICMODELS.EMPLOYEES employees
  ON employees.EmployeeNumber = customers.SalesRepEmployeeNumber

GROUP BY orders.CustomerNumber,
         customers.CustomerName,
         employees.LastName,
         employees.FirstName,
         employees.EmployeeNumber

HAVING COUNT(orders.CustomerNumber) < 4
```

I was also looking over your query, and you **might** get faster (and more efficient results) by using a query like this:

```
WITH CUSTOMERSWITHLESSTHANFOURORDERS
AS
(
  SELECT CUSTOMERNUMBER
  FROM CLASSICMODELS.ORDERS
  GROUP BY CUSTOMERNUMBER
  HAVING COUNT(CUSTOMERNUMBER) < 4
)
SELECT O.CUSTOMERNUMBER,
       C.CUSTOMERNAME,
       E.LASTNAME,
       E.FIRSTNAME,
       E.EMPLOYEENUMBER
FROM CUSTOMERSWITHLESSTHANFOURORDERS O
JOIN CLASSICMODELS.CUSTOMERS C
  ON O.CUSTOMERNUMBER = C.CUSTOMERNUMBER
JOIN CLASSICMODELS.EMPLOYEES E
  ON E.EMPLOYEENUMBER = C.SALESREPEMPLOYEENUMBER;
```

It uses what is called  "common table expression" and basically just isolates a portion of the query. It could be more efficient because it's going to try and group on less data, so it could be faster. Be wary, because there's lots of "could"'s in there because I don't know how various different things are set up in your MySQL database.

Good luck!

Comment: You sir are a genius. I did not know that it was necessary to group by all of them. I can't thank you enough